# Updating a deep component when prop changes in Svelte

Tags: svelte

I have a 2D array representing a board which is initialized and handled at `App.svelte`. I then pass it to a `Board` component, which renders each cell as a `Cell` component, via binding each cell (because it can change itself).

The app simulates a DFS search algorithm, so at a certain point the algorithm runs on the 2D array, and updates it, which registers on `App.svelte`.

How can I register the change to `Board` and consequently to each of the `Cell` components? Do I need to force `Board` to re-render?

Currently when the 2D array changes on `App` the entire board seems to revert to it's original state (although the board contains special cells)

Truncated `App.svelte`:

```
<script>
  import Board from "./Components/Board.svelte";
  import { beforeUpdate } from "svelte";

  var board = [];

  beforeUpdate(() => {
    const rows = LIMIT;
    const columns = LIMIT;
    board = new Array(rows).fill(0).map(() => new Array(columns).fill(0));
  });

  function startSearch() { // Board changes in here
    });
  }
  /**
   * State indexes:
   * 0 = white - Not, but can traverse
   * 1 = blue - Starting point
   * 2 = aquamarine - current cell
   * 3 = orange - End point
   * 4 = gray - wall
   * 5 = black - finished traversing
   */
</script>

<div>
    <Board {board} />
</div>
```

`Board`:

```
<script>
  export let board;
  import Cell from "./Cell.svelte";  
</script>


<div class="board">
  {#each board as row, i}
    <div class="row">
      {#each board[i] as cell, j}
        <Cell bind:cell={cell} {i} {j} />
      {/each}
    </div>
  {/each}
</div>
```

`Cell`:

```
<script>
  export let cell = 0,
    i,
    j;
  let cellDiv;
  import { start, end, state, mouse } from "../stores.js";
  import { afterUpdate } from "svelte";
  let _state = state;
  state.subscribe((val) => {
    _state = val;
  });
  afterUpdate(() => {
    //After updating check if my state changed
    if ($start !== cellDiv && cell === 3) {
      //Check if I'm still endpoint
      cell = $end === cellDiv ? 3 : 0;
      cellDiv.style.backgroundColor = cellToClass();
    }
    if ($end !== cellDiv && cell === 1) {
      //Check if I'm still starting-point
      cell = $start === cellDiv ? 1 : 0;
      cellDiv.style.backgroundColor = cellToClass();
    }
    if (cell === 0 || cell === 5 || cell === 2) {
      cellDiv.style.backgroundColor = cellToClass();
    }
    if (cell === 5 || cell === 2) {
      console.log("x");
      cellDiv.style.backgroundColor = cellToClass();
    }
  });
  function clickHandler() {
    if (_state === 1) {
      //Start point
      if ($end === cellDiv) $end = null;
      $start = cellDiv;
      cell = 1;
    } else if (_state === 3) {
      //End point
      if ($start === cellDiv) $start = null;
      $end = cellDiv;
      cell = 3;
    } else if (_state === 4) {
      //Barriers
      if ($start === cellDiv) $start = null;
      if ($end === cellDiv) $end = null;
      cell = 4;
    }
    cellDiv.style.backgroundColor = cellToClass();
  }
  function handleMouse() {
    if ($mouse && _state === 4) clickHandler();
  }
  function cellToClass() {
    switch (cell) {
      case 0:
        return "white";
      case 1:
        return "dodgerblue";
      case 2:
        return "mediumaquamarine";
      case 3:
        return "rgb(240, 63, 10)";
      case 4:
        return "gray";
      case 5:
        return "black";
      default:
        return "black";
    }
  }
</script>

<div
  class="cell"
  id="{i} {j}"
  bind:this={cellDiv}
  on:mousemove={handleMouse}
  on:click={clickHandler} />
```

[Full untruncated repository](https://github.com/OwenGranot/Search-Algorithms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I register the change to Board and consequently to each of the Cell components? Do I need to force Board to re-render?

Err... Well, yeah. You'll see nothing change if you don't trigger a re-render. Re-render is kind of misleading here though, an "update" would probably be more accurate in respect of what Svelte is doing. A running Svelte app (i.e. once compiled) essentially knows the direct path from a change in state (let variables...) to the corresponding DOM element(s) that need to be updated / recreated, or pieces of state that needs to be recomputed. A "re-render" in Svelte never implies recalculating or recreating everything, even at the component level.

> Currently when the 2D array changes on App the entire board seems to revert to it's original state (although the board contains special cells)

That's because of this code:

```js
  beforeUpdate(() => {
    const rows = LIMIT;
    const columns = LIMIT;
    board = new Array(rows).fill(0).map(() => new Array(columns).fill(0));
  });
```

It runs every time something in `App` changes. It's not what you want. It's too much!

You probably need to run it only once:

```js
  let board = new Array(rows).fill(0).map(() => new Array(columns).fill(0))
```

If you intend on making it configurable, you can make it reactive:

```js
  export let rows = LIMIT
  export let columns = LIMIT

  $: board = new Array(rows).fill(0).map(() => new Array(columns).fill(0))
```

You might think [onMount](https://svelte.dev/docs#onMount) may be a better event, but I don't think it's what you want here either, because you would have an useless render cycle with the empty board, before `onMount` is run. Not dramatic, arguably, but still, initiating your variable right away is slightly better in this case.

The `beforeUpdate` hook is also what's making the store auto-subscription buggy in your `App` component, and preventing you from using the `$start` syntax.